# "This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed" dialog is shown even though there is nothing to be reviewed

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I have recently [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34971256) to the [non-type-template-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-type-template-parameter) excerpt.
The edit is now "no longer reviewable" as seen on that page.

After suggesting the edit, I have unlocked the "Trusted User" privilege. I then edited the tag wiki using this new privilege which bypasses the review system, and the edit got through.

I still see this bugged dialog, even though no edit exists that needs review:
[image]

**Disclaimer: Due to enormous luck or coincidence, all of the tag wikis where I could see such buggy dialogs have turned normal within the last few minutes. It appears to just be a caching issue and the problem can no longer be reproduced.**

Comment: "I still see this bugged dialog" Where are you seeing this dialog?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I saw it on the [info page for the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/non-type-template-parameter/info) until a moment ago. Oddly enough, even though it has been displayed there for multiple days, it now went away. It may just be a really weird caching issue.

Comment: Dialogs like that are usually shown on the page you suggested an edit on. In this case, on the tag wiki info page. It's only shown to the user that suggested the edit, @MisterMiyagi.

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 2):

The suggested edit is no longer reviewable.

Your manual edit after getting the "Trusted User" privilege resulted in the suggested edit being rejected:

[image]

This can be seen in the [activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5740428/jan-schultke?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) of your profile.

The fact that you still saw the *"Thanks for your edit!"* message is probably due to caching. As you stated in the comments, the message now disappeared, so all is as it should be.

Comment: I have noticed that in the meantime. I am now only asking why the buggy dialog is still displayed.

Comment: Probably caching.

Comment: This post does not answer the question. If anything, it just repeats information **in** the question.

Comment: The first revision did ask about what would happen to the review, but apparently that was edited out within the grace period, @yivi.